Can't include raymath.h into my C++ raylib application
I am trying to include "raymath.h" into my C++ raylib project, but I can't seem to get it working, I'm getting a build error.
The way I'm trying to include raymath.h:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "raylib.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "raymath.h"
}

And I'm getting the following error:
raylib-master\src\raymath.h(2552,34): error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax
From what I could understand so far, is that on line 2552 of raymath.h:
float scalex = Vector3Length((Vector3){ a, b, c });

the code is not valid in C++ syntax, but in C.
I assume I am trying to include raymath.h wrong.
I have my project in Microsoft Visual Studio.
I have also tried including raymath without extern "C" {...}, just like raylib.h, but it did not work that way either.

If raymath.h doesn't care about C++ with extern "C" then you can't do anything but posting an issue on their issue tracker. SO unlikely can help you here.

Jep. If you want to ask about ways to fix this, extract a [mcve]. If you know how to fix this, create a pull request against the upstream project.

Just brinstorming... try to #include"raylib.h" inside the extern block

Try re-writing that portion of the code to be like this:
// Extract scale
const float det = aA + bB + c*C;
const Vector3 v;
v.x = a;
v.y = b;
v.zy = c;
float scalex = Vector3Length(v);'
You will likely have to do this is many places.

You may need to convert all of that type of code in raymath.h to the following:
// Extract scale const float det = aA + bB + c*C;
const Vector3 v;
v.x = a; 
v.y = b;
v.z = c;
float scalex = Vector3Length(v);

That should get around the error you are having.
